# Find all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\log n}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\log n}$$ converges.

My work: I tried to find for which $x$ partial sum $$\sum_{n=2}^{m} \sin(nx)$$ is bounded because, we can see that $\frac{1}{\log n}$ is a monotonous sequence that tends to zero, so applying Dirichlet's test, we will get answer.

Partial sum can be written as $$\sum_{n=2}^{m} \sin(nx) = \frac{\sin{\frac{mx}{2}} \sin {\frac{(m+1)x}{2}}}{\sin {\frac{x}{2}}} \leq \frac{1}{\sin \frac{x}{2}}$$

How to conclude this, can I say that it is bounded for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{x}{2}\not = 2k \pi$?

Comment: I think what you wrote is correct. The case for $x/2=2k\pi$ just yields $\sin(nx)=0$ for every $n$ so you can argue that case separately. An alternative way to bound that sum of sines is to look at $\Im\sum_{n=2} e^{n i x}$.

Comment: @daruma Is that something from complex analysis, because I haven't studied that yet

Comment: Oh with that $J$ you mean imaginary part, I got it

Comment: $\sum a_n\sin (nx)$ converges for all $x$ whenever $a_n$ decreases to $0$. Ref: Fourier Series by Edwards.

Answer (score 2):

Here we should use the Dirichlet test. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

We have the following three facts;

$\bullet$ $\frac{1}{\log(n)}$ is monotonically non-increasing.

$\bullet$ $\frac{1}{\log(n)}$ converges to $0$

$\bullet$ For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $C_{x} \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $|\sum_{n=2}^{M}\sin(nx)| \leq C_{x}$ for all $M \geq 2, M \in \mathbb{N}$

Thus by the Dirichlet test, your series converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.